# Getting cannot read properties of undefined error when trying to map through prop generated by getStaticProps function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js, react-props

Hello I'm still new to next and react in general so please bear with me. I've written some code inside the `getStaticProps` next.js function to fetch data from an API, and return it. I know it's being properly processed because I can console log it inside the `getStaticProps` func with no issues. But when I go into my `ActiveCases` function and try and extract it from props I get *undefined*. Can anyone help with getting the data from `getStaticProps`, into props and then pull it to display on my page?

I'm also using Axios to fetch the API if that matters.

Another note if there is anything in my code which would not be considered best practice/is done diffrently at companies and large scale next/react apps please let me know what I should change.

Full code below

**getStaticProps function**

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://covid-19-statistics.p.rapidapi.com/regions',
        headers: {
          'x-rapidapi-host': 'covid-19-statistics.p.rapidapi.com',
          'x-rapidapi-key': 'API_KEY_REMOVED'
        }
    };
    const result = await axios.request(options);
    const dataFromResult = result.data.data;
    let data = [];

    dataFromResult.map(async (item, index) => {
        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://covid-19-statistics.p.rapidapi.com/reports',
            params: {
              iso: item.iso,
              region_name: item.name,
              date: '2022-01-14'
            },
            headers: {
              'x-rapidapi-host': 'covid-19-statistics.p.rapidapi.com',
              'x-rapidapi-key': 'API_KEY_REMOVED'
            }
          };

        const result = await axios.request(options);
        const dataV = result.data.data[0];
        let region;

        if (dataV?.region === undefined) {
            region = item.name;
        } else {
            region = dataV.region;
        }

        if (dataV === undefined) return;

        const dataStructure = {
            "country_name": item.name,
            "cases": dataV.confirmed,
            "deaths": dataV.deaths,
            "recovered": dataV.recovered,
            "active": dataV.active,
            "fatality_rate": dataV.fatality_rate,
            "date": dataV.date,
            "last_update": dataV.last_update,
            "region": region
        }
        
        data = [
            ...data,
            { dataStructure }
        ]
    })

    return {
        props: { 
            data,
        }
    }
}
```

**ActiveCases react function component**

```
export default function ActiveCases({ data }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Active Cases</h1>
            { data.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <div key={index}>
                        <p>Country: {item.dataStructure.country_name} </p>
                        <p>Cases: {item.dataStructure.cases}</p>
                    </div>
                )
            }) }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is `map` is returning an array of `promise` instead of data.

You can do sth like this:

```
await Promise.all(dataFromResult.map(async (item, index) => {
    const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://covid-19-statistics.p.rapidapi.com/reports',
            params: {
              iso: item.iso,
              region_name: item.name,
              date: '2022-01-14'
            },
            headers: {
              'x-rapidapi-host': 'covid-19-statistics.p.rapidapi.com',
              'x-rapidapi-key': 'API_KEY_REMOVED'
            }
          };

        const result = await axios.request(options);
        const dataV = result.data.data[0];
        let region;

        if (dataV?.region === undefined) {
            region = item.name;
        } else {
            region = dataV.region;
        }

        if (dataV === undefined) return;

        const dataStructure = {
            "country_name": item.name,
            "cases": dataV.confirmed,
            "deaths": dataV.deaths,
            "recovered": dataV.recovered,
            "active": dataV.active,
            "fatality_rate": dataV.fatality_rate,
            "date": dataV.date,
            "last_update": dataV.last_update,
            "region": region
        }
        
        data = [
            ...data,
            { dataStructure }
        ]
    })

    return {
        props: { 
            data,
        }
    }
}));
```